# Error in createMAE function: non-unique values when setting 'row.names' in TCGA LIHC Data

Tags: r, rna-seq, bioconductor, methylation

I am working with the `createMAE()` function of the ELMER Bioconductor package. While executing the `createMAE()` function using TCGA LIHC DNA Methylation 450K and RNASeq HTSeq - Counts data, I am getting this error:

```
Error in.rowNamesDF <-(x, value = value) :

duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

In addition: Warning message:

non-unique values when setting 'row.names': 'TCGA-DD-AACA-02A', 'TCGA-DD-AACA-02B'
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of such error?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: R requires unique row names on data frames and some of the "values" that you are trying to set as row names are non-unique.

You will need to provide a vector i) of length the same as your row number, ii) that is composed of non-unique values.